# Apache Reverse Proxy ReWrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, proxy

I have a apache instance setup to reverse proxy an internal application. I have this working using mod_proxy, but the end result is a lack of images and other content due to hard coded paths in the application itself. I think I have two options.

- Mod_Rewrite
- Mod_HTML

The basic problem is this.

External site: http://external.customer.com (Port 80)
Internal site: http://internal.supplier.com:8080/testcustomer

I need to get apache to proxy the connection, but it must use the full URL when talking to the internal server internal.supplier.com:8080/testcustomer and paths must be rewritten so that images etc will render on the end client.

Can anyone give me some guidance here? help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That may be becuse you have used absolute paths like `src=/app/favicon.jpg` and `src=/app/icons/smiley.jpg`......instead of relative paths like using `src="favicon.jpg"`.

This problem can be solved by adding module mod_proxy_html which helps in parsing html.

Then LoadModule proxy_html in your httpd.conf and then add following directives :-

```
ProxyHTMLEnable On
```

OR

```
SetOutputFilter proxy-html
```

mod_proxy_hmtl has pre-requisite installs libxml2 and libxml2-devel.You can install it through yum.

If you could share your configuration file then may be we can help more.