# Apache rewrite while acting as a reverse proxy

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy

- I have example.com:8080/second running on Apache Tomcat.
- I have Apache2 as a reverse proxy serving pages as example.com on
  port 80
- A lot of the code is pointing to the 'second' directory, however
  because Apache is acting as a reverse proxy to
  example.com:8080/second that 'second' directory can not be seen by
  the browser.

I want to use an apache rewrite to redirect anything going to the second folder to the root or / of the site. However I when I go to http://example.com/second/css/style.css it does not pull up http://example.com/css/style.css

I tried the following:
[Apache Reverse Proxy ReWrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21833884/apache-reverse-proxy-rewrite)
but when I put ProxyHTMLEnable On in my conf file apache fails to start.

This is what I am trying now. Apache does start but I am not getting the desired redirect effect:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAdmin admin@example.com

        SetEnvIf Request_URI ".(jpg|jpeg|png|swf|css|gif|dat|ico|js)$" dontlog

        #SetEnvIf Request_URI "/cron/" dontlog
        LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" varnishcombined

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule ^second/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
       # ProxyRequests Off
       # <Proxy *>
       #   Order deny,allow
       #   Allow from all
       # </Proxy>
        ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/second/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/second/
        <Location />
          Order allow,deny
          Allow from all
        </Location>
   </VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below setting in conf file because I am able to succeed with 0.0.0.0.

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:8080/second/
ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:8080/second/
```

Comment: I replaced the ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse lines in my config with you 3 lines and restarted apache. The example.com pulls up fine, but if i try example.com/second/css/style.css I get a 404. I need that url to forward to example.com/css/style.css